# Python homework problem without using IF Statement

Tags: python

Is there a better way to write this code **without** using an if statement?

```
current_hour = 12
current_minute = 37
current_section = "PM"
due_hour = 9
due_minute = 0
due_section = "AM"
```

Given the current time and deadline time represented by the variables above, determine if an assignment is eligible if the time represented by `current_hour`, `current_minute`, and `current_section` is before the time represented by `due_hour`, `due_minute` and `due_section`. I created this but its not always working:

```
current=current_hour*60 + current_minute
due = due_hour*60 + due_minute
print(current < due and current_section < due_section)
```

Comment: FWIW: Tuples are comparable in Python.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network ([Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com))

Comment: can you please clarity?

Comment: how do I account for am and pm?

Comment: Thank you for the Tuples reference

Comment: I think I also found a solution:

Comment: current_time=(current_hour%12+12*(current_section=="PM"))*60+current_minute
due_time=(due_hour%12+12*(due_section=="PM"))*60+due_minute
print(current_time < due_time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking advantage of comparison of `bool` and `tuple` objects, this is easily written as

```
(current_section=="PM",current_hour%12,current_minute)<(due_section=="PM",due_hour%12,due_minute)
```

Of course, canonicalizing into a number of minutes since midnight is more general:

```
s=(hour%12+12*(section=="PM"))*60+minute
```

…which can be made a function to be applied to any number of times.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using a variation of your code, thank you:

Comment: current_time=(current_hour%12+12*(current_section=="PM"))*60+current_minute
due_time=(due_hour%12+12*(due_section=="PM"))*60+due_minute
print(current_time < due_time)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it without a single if:

```
from datetime import datetime

def to24(h: int, m: int, s: str) -> datetime:
  m: str = str(h) + ':' + str(m) + " " + s;
  return datetime.strptime(m, '%I:%M %p');

def is_valid(h1: int, m1: int, s1: str, h2: int, m2: int, s2: str) -> bool:
  return to24(h1, m1, s1) <= to24(h2, m2, s2);


def main() -> int:
  current_hour = 1;
  current_minute = 0;
  current_section = "AM";
  due_hour = 12;
  due_minute = 0;
  due_section = "PM";
  print(
    is_valid(
      current_hour,
      current_minute,
      current_section,
      due_hour,
      due_minute,
      due_section,
    )
  );

  return 0;

__name__ == "__main__" and main(); # See how this avoids `if` :D
```

Comment: Now it puts 1 pm before 2 am.  This sort of problem is notoriously difficult to get right for how simple it is; the tuple approach is your friend (although watch out for 12<1).

Comment: @DavisHerring You're right. Tried to fix it again just for contrast

Comment: I agree.  it seems so simple but it is really a complicated one

Comment: so far it still gets errors when trying the various examples.  I think it has to do with the AM or PM

Comment: @DavisHerring I am sure it's fine now!

Comment: @JasonBar Consider this

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's assistance.  It helped to really think more about the problem and various ways to try to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

First you want to check for 'AM' and 'PM'

```
print(current_section < due_section)
```

And then you want to convert the time in minute and compare them

```
current_time = current_hour*60+current_minute
due_time = due_hour*60+due_minute
print(current_time < due_time)
```

Combine the two of them:

```
print(current_section < due_section or current_time < due_time)
```

> If `current_section < due_section` is True, it will ignore the second statement.

Comment: You can just count pm as 12 hours (and 12 hours as 0).

Comment: @DavisHerring This would include dictionnaries or something like this and for someone that doesn't want to use if statement...